# How to play a video from the Internet in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, video, mediaelement

I want to play a video from the Internet in WPF. I used the code below. It can play the video but it always breaks down and the speed is very slow. I don't know how to solve this problem.

```
mediaElement.MediaFailed += mediaElement_MediaFailed;
mediaElement.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Play;
mediaElement.Source = new Uri(@"http://media2.neu6.edu.cn/hls/cctv6hd.m3u8", UriKind.Absolute);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand this is a long term issue with Media Element itself. Try using [WPFMediaKit](https://wpfmediakit.codeplex.com/)
instead.